# Why does one need Google's WaveNet model to generate audio if it already takes audio as input?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I've spent a lot of time trying to understand the [Google's WaveNet work](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.03499.pdf) (also used in their DeepVoice model), but still confused about some very basic aspects. I'm referring to [this Tensorflow implementation of Wavenet.](https://github.com/Rayhane-mamah/Tacotron-2/blob/master/wavenet_vocoder/models/wavenet.py)

Page-2 of the paper says:

> "*In this paper we introduce a new generative model operating directly
>   on the raw audio waveform.*".

If we already have *raw audio waveform*, why do we need WaveNet? Isn't that what model is supposed to generate?

When I print out the model it shows `input` as just 1 float value in `input_convolution` kernel as its shape is 1x1x128. What is that 1 float in the input representing? Am I missing something?

```
 `inference/input_convolution/kernel:0 (float32_ref 1x1x128) [128, bytes: 512`]
```

more layers below:

```
---------
Variables: name (type shape) [size]
---------
inference/ConvTranspose1D_layer_0/kernel:0 (float32_ref 1x11x80x80) [70400, bytes: 281600]
inference/ConvTranspose1D_layer_0/bias:0 (float32_ref 80) [80, bytes: 320]
inference/ConvTranspose1D_layer_1/kernel:0 (float32_ref 1x25x80x80) [160000, bytes: 640000]
inference/ConvTranspose1D_layer_1/bias:0 (float32_ref 80) [80, bytes: 320]
inference/input_convolution/kernel:0 (float32_ref 1x1x128) [128, bytes: 512]
inference/input_convolution/bias:0 (float32_ref 128) [128, bytes: 512]
inference/ResidualConv1DGLU_0/residual_block_causal_conv_ResidualConv1DGLU_0/kernel:0 (float32_ref 3x128x256) [98304, bytes: 393216]
inference/ResidualConv1DGLU_0/residual_block_causal_conv_ResidualConv1DGLU_0/bias:0 (float32_ref 256) [256, bytes: 1024]
inference/ResidualConv1DGLU_0/residual_block_cin_conv_ResidualConv1DGLU_0/kernel:0 (float32_ref 1x80x256) [20480, bytes: 81920]
inference/ResidualConv1DGLU_0/residual_block_cin_conv_ResidualConv1DGLU_0/bias:0 (float32_ref 256) [256, bytes: 1024]
inference/ResidualConv1DGLU_0/residual_block_skip_conv_ResidualConv1DGLU_0/kernel:0 (float32_ref 1x128x128) [16384, bytes: 65536]
inference/ResidualConv1DGLU_0/residual_block_skip_conv_ResidualConv1DGLU_0/bias:0 (float32_ref 128) [128, bytes: 512]
inference/ResidualConv1DGLU_0/residual_block_out_conv_ResidualConv1DGLU_0/kernel:0 (float32_ref 1x128x128) [16384, bytes: 65536]
inference/ResidualConv1DGLU_0/residual_block_out_conv_ResidualConv1DGLU_0/bias:0 (float32_ref 128) [128, bytes: 512]
inference/ResidualConv1DGLU_1/residual_block_causal_conv_ResidualConv1DGLU_1/kernel:0 (float32_ref 3x128x256) [98304, bytes: 393216]
inference/ResidualConv1DGLU_1/residual_block_causal_conv_ResidualConv1DGLU_1/bias:0 (float32_ref 256) [256, bytes: 1024]
inference/ResidualConv1DGLU_1/residual_block_cin_conv_ResidualConv1DGLU_1/kernel:0 (float32_ref 1x80x256) [20480, bytes: 81920]
inference/ResidualConv1DGLU_1/residual_block_cin_conv_ResidualConv1DGLU_1/bias:0 (float32_ref 256) [256, bytes: 1024]
inference/ResidualConv1DGLU_1/residual_block_skip_conv_ResidualConv1DGLU_1/kernel:0 (float32_ref 1x128x128) [16384, bytes: 65536]
inference/ResidualConv1DGLU_1/residual_block_skip_conv_ResidualConv1DGLU_1/bias:0 (float32_ref 128) [128, bytes: 512]
inference/ResidualConv1DGLU_1/residual_block_out_conv_ResidualConv1DGLU_1/kernel:0 (float32_ref 1x128x128) [16384, bytes: 65536]
inference/ResidualConv1DGLU_1/residual_block_out_conv_ResidualConv1DGLU_1/bias:0 (float32_ref 128) [128, bytes: 512]
```

Answer (score 1):

The generative networks typically operate on conditional probability of getting `new_element` given `old_element(s)`. In math terms:

[image: conditional probability]

as defined in the Google paper. As you can see, the network needs to start from something (the `x1...xt-1` - the past values) , it cannot go from scratch. You can think of it as if the network needs a theme that will tell it what genre you are interested in; heavy metal and country have *somewhat different* vibe.

If you like, you can generate this starter waveform yourself: a sine wave, white noise or something more complex. Once you run the network, it will start outputting new values that will eventually become an input to it.

Comment: so how does the network generate the first or first few output values as there are no input present at that point? Per the `input_convolution` kernel shown above it's operating on the input so what happens at output step 0, output step 1 and so on.

Comment: Also, why is the input to `input_convollution` above only 1-channel and output 128-channel in `input_convolution/kernel:0 (float32_ref 1x1x128) `?  which layer is forming the `mu-law` encoding used in WaveNet, could you elaborate?